# How do I remove the axle protector after shipping

Tags: road-bike, transportation

I recently purchased a road bike, and while assembling it I found a piece of plastic to protect the bottom of the fork legs. A mountain biker, I always used different protection for that part and am not sure how to get it off I tried pulling fairly hard, and I'm a decently strong guy, but am I just being wimpy? It seems to be a solid piece of plastic except for some rectangular holes underneath the legs. Is there something I'm missing? After some research, this is what the part looks like: [image]

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After growing somewhat impatient, I grew a pair, set the fork (protected by the guard) on the ground, set my foot on the protector, and pulled up on the legs as hard as I could. It came off, but as a cautionary note to anyone else with this problem, I took a brake to the shin. Watch your shins

Comment: +1 for taking a brake to the shin for educational purposes